# How to automate login and backing up with Perl

Tags: javascript, html, perl, web

I'm trying to login into the web configuration panel of a device (for the test  I'm using my router) and create backup. The module is WWW::Scripter. The page is using JavaScript. I think that I'm not passing the parameters properly because it returns error :

```
No such field 'userName' at /home/angel/perl5/lib/perl5/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 750.
```

JS function on the web page:

```
function CheckUserPswInvalid()
{
var userName = $("userName");
var pcPassword = $("pcPassword");   
if(!CheckUserPswChars(userName.value))
{
    userName.select();
    userName.focus();
    return false;   
}

if(!CheckUserPswChars(pcPassword.value))
{
    pcPassword.select();
    pcPassword.focus();
    return false;   
}

return true;
}
```

My code:

```
use WWW::Scripter;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $url  = 'http://192.168.0.1/';
my $username = 'username';
my $pass = 'password';
my $agent = new WWW::Scripter;

$agent->use_plugin('JavaScript');
$agent->get('http://192.168.0.1/');
$agent->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new);
$agent->form_name("loginForm");
$agent->field('userName' => $username);
$agent->field("pcPassword" => $pass);
$agent->submit();
```

EDIT: Adding part of the HTML:

```
` <div class="loginBox">    
    <div class="noteDiv">
        <span id="note"></span>
        <span id="tip"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panelThre" align="center">
        <div align="center" class="picDiv" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li id="unLi" class="unLi"><input class="text" id="userName" type="text" maxlength="15" /></li>
                <li class="blank"></li>
                <li id="pwLi" class="pwLi"><input class="text" id="pcPassword" type="password" maxlength="15"/></li>
            </ul>
            <label id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" onclick="PCSubWin()"/></label>
            <div>
            <label id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 TP-LINK Technologies Co., Ltd. All rights reserved. </label>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form action="/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm" method="get" id="loginForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="Save" name="Save" />
</form>
```

`

Comment: You're going to need to add a link to the web page or the text of its source.   The error means that the script can't find a form element with the name "userName".

Comment: The jQuery you have shown uses tag names, not form `name` attributes or IDs. `$("userName")` is similar to `$("body")`, which will get all `<body>` tags. So yours will get `<userName>` tags, which makes sense for XML, but not really HTML. We'll need a lot more information.

Comment: [Crossposted](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1232628) to PerlMonks.

Comment: Added the part of the HTML that contains the form

Comment: `$` not necessarily means jQuery. Considering where this application is running, it's much more likely that's just a shortcut for `document.getElementById`. – Edit: I'm convinced it is so, the naked `value` property fits type `HTMLInputElement`, but not type `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the DOM and submitting via callback:

```
$agent->document->getElementById('userName')->value($username);
$agent->document->getElementById('pcPassword')->value($pass);
$agent->eval('PCSubWin()');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure WWW::Mechanize wouldn't work for this:

1. There's no form (no `<form>` tag in HTML);
2. The input field doesn't have a name and `$agent->field` takes field name as a parameter, rather than ID.

JavaScript probably issues an Ajax request. I suggest that you find the Ajax request in your browser development console and replay it (you don't need `WWW::Mechanize` for that, `LWP::UserAgent` should do). HTH.

Comment: This question is about WWW::Scripter.

Comment: `WWW::Scripter` is a subclass of `WWW::Mechanize`. `field` method is inherited from Mechanize.